# Get hour from user and store in rails model + timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails view where the user is presented with a dropdown displaying the hours '00:00', '01:00' etc.

Once the user has selected this hour, then it is stored in the model with some other fields.

My application is working in timezone UTC+2 (I have set `config.time_zone = 'Jerusalem'`). 
At what stage to I related to timezones when handling this time on its path from the view to the model? If I use e.g. `DateTime.strptime("10:00", "%H:%M").in_time_zone(Time.zone)`, then I get a time at '12:00' - while what I really would like is for the database to store in UTF (which should be `08:00` while the rest of the site works with local time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TZInfo ruby library http://tzinfo.rubyforge.org and convert your time with following method

```
def local_to_utc(date, time_zone)
  begin
    unless time_zone.nil?
      tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get(time_zone)
      return tz.local_to_utc(date)
    end
  rescue 
    return nil
  end
end
```